# Can't delete single value in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a big trouble with my code I'm actually doing an API for My hero academia project (heroes,agencies,vilains).
Spring boot is amazing tool I can get my agencies (also by id and name).
But I can't delete my agency by id (i can delete all the table).
I'm on spring environement.

Here's the code that I'm trying to make it work. This code is in a class named AgenciesDao :

```
 @Transactional
    public boolean deleteById(Integer id) {
        Session session;
        session = getSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        getSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM AgenciesEntity WHERE id=:id").setInteger("id", id);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    }
```

The class AgenciesDao extends from a class named HibernateInteractions with basics interactions with my db.
HibernateInteractions  :

```
package com.Dao;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class HibernateInteractions<T> implements CrudOperations<T> {
    private static SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;
    private Session session;
    public HibernateInteractions() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
            session=getSession();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        return ourSessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    @Override
    public int create(T obj) {
        Transaction tx = null;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Serializable id = session.save(obj);
        tx.commit();
        return (int) id;
    }
    @Override
    public T find(Integer id,Class<T>tClass) {
        return session.find(tClass, id);

    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(Class<T> tClass) {
        return session.createQuery("from " + tClass.getName()).getResultList();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(T obj) {
        Transaction tx;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.merge(obj);
        tx.commit();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean delete(T obj) {
        Transaction tx;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.remove(obj);
        tx.commit();
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteAll(Class<T> tClass) {
        Transaction tx;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.createQuery("DELETE FROM "+tClass.getName()).executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work.
Here's my controller :

```
@DeleteMapping()
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteAgency(@PathParam("id")Integer id,@PathParam("name")String name){
   AgenciesDao agenciesDao=new AgenciesDao();
    if(id!=null){
        agenciesDao.deleteById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Supression ok",HttpStatus.OK);
    } else if (name!=null) {
        agenciesDao.deleteByName(name);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Supression ok",HttpStatus.OK);

    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

}
```

And here's what's in my Agency table :
[Agency table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lll5I.png)
Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Note that (1) you shouldn't generally use Hibernate `Session`; it's outdated in favor of the standardized `EntityManager`, and (2) unless you're required to write this code yourself for your assignment, using a Spring Data JPA `AgencyRepository extends JpaRepository` will auto-generate all these queries for you.

Comment: aren't you forgetting to `executeUpdate` in your `deleteById`? anyway as suggested use Spring Data Jpa

Comment: I'm new on Spring and didn't know that JpaRepository I will take a look at it thank you very much. Oh yes I've forgotten the executeupdate.... Sorry :) But I learnt something !